# Xpath : Convert Number to equivalent String

Tags: xml, xpath

Is it possible to convert number to equivalent alphabet.

```
Ex : If count(preceding::title) = 1 -> It should return 'A'.
```

For sure there are not more than 10 numbers which means only upto A to J are valid.

pls assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
substring('ABCDEFGHIJ', count(preceding::title), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom !

Comment: That's a very nice solution.